# Looking for a tool for inspecting SMPP packets

Tags: smpp

Do you know any tool that can be used for visually inspecting SMPP packets? A tool that accepts a byte array or string as input and lets us check the fields quickly.

I searched alot but all of the tools were actually code libraries instead of being a tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wireshark has the capability to recognize SMPP packets when given a tcpdump.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a commercial product that can inspect SMPP traffic and apply actions when a byte/string pattern is matched: http://tritux.com/product/NetCop

I'm involved in the tech team behind this product, some of its basic usage is to inspect SMPP traffic to detect deliver_sm PDUs and check for per-subscriber throughput, if one subscriber is sending deliver_sm PDUs more than (let's say) 6 per second than it is more likely to be a malicious mobile terminal (maybe a simbox) flooding the SMSC with MO traffic, NetCop is able to take actions like:

- Sending a notification to the user
- Blocking (barring) SMS-MO traffic on user (through the telco's intelligent network integration)
- ...